# Is it allowed to ask questions where others can each share their opinion?

Tags: discussion, questions, scope, opinion-based

I want to ask a question in Stack Overflow about what I should do, and everyone can share every opinion.

But, I guess everyone will mark this question as "Opinion-based", right?

So can I ask this question?

Comment: Looks like you already knew the answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You **can't** ask opinion-based questions. In fact, there's no Stack Exchange site where you can, it's one of the close reasons:

[image: Opinion-based]

The Stack Exchange network is for **Q&A** (questions and answers). And not for meant *"opinion-based"* answers. Aside, questions need to be *specific*. This isn't a discussion forum.

You might want to consider maybe asking it in a Stack Overflow chat room.

You can read about [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer! What I'm trying to ask is: "What should I do if the .dart file is not used?" I think this is an opinion-based question, right?

Comment: Well, maybe Stack Overflow is not the place to ask my question

Comment: Even aside from the question of opinion vs. fact, Stack Overflow is not a place to get others to make decisions for you, and certainly not to determine the requirements of your program. We need **concrete, specific** problems, in order to have concrete, specific **questions** to answer. Stack Overflow is **not a discussion forum**; the latter is what you want for this. Please try Reddit or Quora.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel ok

Comment: Yes you *can*. But you *shouldn't*. Big difference. It is a matter of personal responsibility, to not only know the (documented) house rules but also to follow them.